# dynamically adding functions to a Python module

Tags: python, metaprogramming, decorator

Our framework requires wrapping certain functions in some ugly boilerplate code:

```
def prefix_myname_suffix(obj):
    def actual():
        print 'hello world'
    obj.register(actual)
    return obj
```

I figured this might be simplified with a decorator:

```
@register
def myname():
    print 'hello world'
```

However, that turned out to be rather tricky, mainly because the framework looks for a certain pattern of function names at module level.

I've tried the following within the decorator, to no avail:

```
current_module = __import__(__name__)
new_name = prefix + func.__name__ + suffix
# method A
current_module[new_name] = func
# method B
func.__name__ = new_name
current_module += func
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to explain what and how the framework "looks" for in these names a little more thoroughly. You can probably override __getattr__ or swizzle your module's own dictionary to fake it out, but it's impossible to say for certain at this point.

Comment: I honestly don't know what exactly the framework does. Oren's little reminder was what I needed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use either

```
current_module.new_name = func
```

or

```
setattr(current_module, new_name, func)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution to your problem would be to make the decorated function act as the original function.

Try using the function `mergeFunctionMetadata` from Twisted, found here:
[twisted/python/util.py](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-8.1.0/twisted/python/util.py)

It makes your decorated function act as the original, hopefully making the framework pick it up.

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting - will have to look into how best to apply this.

Comment: moved https://github.com/racker/python-twisted-core/blob/master/twisted/python/util.py#L805