# How to dynamically create module level functions from methods in a class

Tags: python, metaprogramming, fabric

I am trying to dynamically create module level functions from the methods in a class. So for every method in a class, I want to create a function with the same name which creates an instance of the class and then calls the method.

The reason I want to do this is so I can take an object-oriented approach to creating Fabric files. Since Fabric will call module level functions but not methods of a class, this is my work-around.

I have used the following links to get me started

- [How do I get list of methods in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-you-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class)
- [dynamically adding functions to a Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621350/dynamically-adding-functions-to-a-python-module)
- [How do I call setattr() on the current module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933470/how-do-i-call-setattr-on-the-current-module)
- [The Python getattr Function](https://web.archive.org/web/20200703234823/http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm)
- [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)
- [How to modify the local namespace in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142068/how-to-modify-the-local-namespace-in-python)

And I have come up with the following code

```
import inspect
import sys
import types

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method1(self, arg1):
        print 'method 1 %s' % arg1

    def method2(self):
        print 'method 2'

def fabric_class_to_function_magic(module_name):
    # get the module as an object
    print module_name
    module_obj = sys.modules[module_name]
    print dir(module_obj)

    # Iterate over the methods of the class and dynamically create a function
    # for each method that calls the method and add it to the current module
    for method in inspect.getmembers(TestClass, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
        print
        print method
        method_name, method_obj = method

        # create a new template function which calls the method
        def newfunc_template(*args, **kwargs):
            tc = TestClass()
            func = getattr(tc, method_name)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        # create the actual function
        print 'code: ', newfunc_template.func_code
        print 'method_name: ', method_name
        newfunc = types.FunctionType(newfunc_template.func_code,
                                     {'TestClass': TestClass,
                                      'getattr': getattr,
                                      'method_name': method_name,
                                      },
                                     name=method_name,
                                     argdefs=newfunc_template.func_defaults,
                                     closure=newfunc_template.func_closure,
                                     )

        # add the new function to the current module
        setattr(module_obj, method_name, newfunc)

# test the dynamically created module level function
thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
print dir(thismodule)
fabric_class_to_function_magic(__name__)
print dir(thismodule)
method1('arg1')
method2()
```

And I get the following error

```
['TestClass', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'fabric_class_to_function_magic', 'inspect', 'sys', 'thismodule', 'types']
__main__
['TestClass', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'fabric_class_to_function_magic', 'inspect', 'sys', 'thismodule', 'types']

('__init__', <unbound method TestClass.__init__>)
code:  <code object newfunc_template at 0x7f8800a28d50, file "test.py", line 85>
method_name:  __init__

('method1', <unbound method TestClass.method1>)
code:  <code object newfunc_template at 0x7f8800a28d50, file "test.py", line 85>
method_name:  method1

('method2', <unbound method TestClass.method2>)
code:  <code object newfunc_template at 0x7f8800a28d50, file "test.py", line 85>
method_name:  method2
['TestClass', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__init__', '__name__', '__package__', 'fabric_class_to_function_magic', 'inspect', 'method1', 'method2', 'sys', 'thismodule', 'types']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 111, in <module>
    method1('arg1')
  File "test.py", line 88, in newfunc_template
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: method2() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

It seems to be reusing the reference to the function? Any ideas?

UPDATE: Here is the working code with Ned Batchelder's fix

```
def fabric_class_to_function_magic(module_name):
    # get the module as an object
    module_obj = sys.modules[module_name]

    # Iterate over the methods of the class and dynamically create a function
    # for each method that calls the method and add it to the current module
    for method in inspect.getmembers(TestClass, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
        method_name, method_obj = method

        # get the bound method
        tc = TestClass()
        func = getattr(tc, method_name)

        # add the function to the current module
        setattr(module_obj, method_name, func)
```

UPDATE 2: Here is my blog post on the subject: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/09/class-based-fabric-scripts-metaprogramming-hack/

Comment: oddly enough, you should also set `func.__module__ = module_name` in order for it to describe itself properly... otherwise it will report its module as the one containing `fabric_class_to_function_magic` instead of the target module!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're over-thinking your solution.  Change the end of `fabric_class_to_function_magic` to be this:

```
    tc = TestClass()
    func = getattr(tc, method_name)

    # add the new function to the current module
    setattr(module_obj, method_name, func)
```

and it works fine.  No need to make a new function object, you already have one returned by getattr on your object.  The bound method returned by getattr is a callable thing.  Just assign it to your module attribute, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

actually your code is right but when return func(*args, **kwargs) executes, args will pass empty tuple like () and there are no parameters in your method2, so it raises such exception,

a quick solution towards your problem would be, like

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method1(self, arg1):
        print 'method 1 %s' % arg1

    def method2(self, *args, **kw):
        print 'method 2'
```

Comment: This makes the error go away, but the underlying problem still exists. Now it prints "method 2" twice.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to someone:

```
import inspect
import sys

def get_functions_from_class_in_module_and_extract_to_module(module, *args, class_config={}, **kwargs):

    classes = dict(tuple(x) for x in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[module.__name__], inspect.isclass))

    for cls_name, cls in classes.items():

        class_instance = cls(**class_config[cls_name])

        functions = dict(tuple(x) for x in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.isfunction))

        for function_name, func in functions.items():
                
            class_func = lambda *args, **kwargs: func(class_instance, *args, **kwargs)

            setattr(module, function_name, class_func)
```